# How can I pass a Dictionary variable to a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, view, actionlink

I have an action link in ASP.NET MVC 5 and want to pass a `Dictionary<string, int>` variable to it.

Here is my view code.

```
@*Get the dictionary property from the current model and pass it to the action link*@
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Click this link", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { dict = Model.Dict }, null)
</p>
```

And here is my controller code.

```
//Get the dictionary variable and pass it to the new view
public ActionResult ActionName(Dictionary<string, int> dict)
{
    return View(dict);
}
```

When I click the action link in my web application, I reach the correct `ActionResult` but the `dict` parameter contains no elements. How can I fix this problem so that my Dictionary variable can be passed via the action link.

Comment: You want actually to pass a Dictionary object to Controller, not View.

Comment: You cannot pass complex objects as route parameters. Internally the method generates the route values by calling the `.ToString()` method on each value (look at the `href` attribute your generating)